# Location of Add/Delete Buttons for an NSTableView in OS X

Tags: macos, xib, nstableview

I think I must be missing something simple but being new to Xcode... Specifically I am coding in Swift but I believe this is more of a .xib file question. It is easy to have add and delete buttons outside of an NSTableView (like the native Mail app's Preferences->Signatures panel) but how do you integrate these into what seems to be the NSTableView itself? (more like the native Mail app's Preferences->Accounts panel) Ideally I want the option to have more than just add / delete buttons present but once I understand the process adding more functionality should be easy.

[image: Example of Signatures panel vs Accounts panel layout]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These buttons are not integrated, it's just an `NSSegmentedControl` aligned to the bottom of the table view.

[image]

To get this particular appearance of the `NSSegmentedControl`

- Set `Style` to `Small Square`
- Set `Mode` to `Momentary`
- Set the `Image` of Segment 0 to `NSAddTemplate`
- Set the `Image` of Segment 1 to `NSRemoveTemplate`
- Set the `width` of Segment 0 and 1 to `Auto`
- Set the `width` of Segment 2 to a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

The particular example you showed is just some buttons in a container view abutting the bottom of the scroll view that contains the table view. The container view draws a background to match the buttons and a border. It's probably actually "underlapping" the scroll view by a point so you don't get a doubled border between them.

In fact, if you look carefully, the container view is one point too narrow, so that its right border doesn't match the right border of the scroll view. That kind of proves that it's not part of or in the scroll view.

Comment: Okay, I figured there was something going on outside of the actual NSTableView due to the small anomaly you spotted -- but my newbie followup question is what is a "container view" in IB? Is that another View Controller just being used to create a boarder or something else?

Comment: It's just a view into which you put other views. In the object list, it will be labeled Custom View. If you can achieve the desired appearance with standard view attributes, you don't have to use a custom view. It will just be an instance of `NSView`. Otherwise, you'll have to write your own subclass of `NSView` and set the Custom View's class to your subclass in the Identity inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question & I posted an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237107/6141587) :)

But what I think is its a NSView containing 2 NSButtons for + & - as posted in my answer linked above.

Comment: No, it's a `NSSegmentedControl`

Comment: Yeah you can use it too. I used button for my use case although its a bit different. I thought Segmented Control didn't have the width after the - & I didn't knew how to set it. Thanks for explaining in the answer. I just have 15 days of Swift experience although. Thanks for correcting.