# How to build Insert Remove Form with Xcode Object Library for Cocoa Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift4

[Rocket for Mac](https://matthewpalmer.net/rocket/) has a **Preferences** Window in which it has a form like below to insert & remove an app.

I want to make a form like that but how should I build it? I am new to Cocoa development so this might be obvious.

I want to make the one with the label **Disable Rocket within these apps:**

[image: Rocket Preferences Window Form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

What I did was use `NSTableView` with single column for the textbox. And made the `NSTextField` in it to be text editable using the **Behaviour** attribute.

Then for the + & - button I used 2 `NSPopupButton` & made the `Image` attribute to be `NSAddTemplate` & `NSRemoveTemplate` which exists by default in Xcode. There are bunch of other images that are default in it.

That solved it for me :)