# What is the name of this macOS UI Control?

Tags: macos, user-interface

What is the name?

Is this an aggregation of controls (buttons and editable list) or a single control?

[image: screenshot of the component]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523078/location-of-add-delete-buttons-for-an-nstableview-in-os-x/52242289#52242289. It's a table and a segmented control (SwiftUI version).

Comment: Ok, That answers on how to compose one.